# Java log4j check sys or env in properties for migration from elastic beanstalk to Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Our team is migrating from elastic beanstalk to kubernetes.

We have log4j configuration and have the below configuration for logging to sentry.

In our config, we use this setup for elastic beanstalk

```
    <Sentry name="Sentry"
            minimumBreadcrumbLevel="DEBUG"
            minimumEventLevel="WARN"
            dsn="${sys:sentry.dsn}"/>
```

This works for elastic beanstalk as we can pass configurations in as system properties using the UI configuration.

In kubernetes, these are now passed in as environment variables requiring the following configuration

```
    <Sentry name="Sentry"
            minimumBreadcrumbLevel="DEBUG"
            minimumEventLevel="WARN"
            dsn="${env:sentry.dsn}"/>
```

I'd like both options to work as we go through the transition process.

My question is, how do I pass environment variables in Kubernetes and have them show up as system properties.